# The Canadian dividend tax credit: Why is it that someone can earn a lot in dividends but pay no/little tax?

Tags: canada, income-tax, taxes, dividends, tax-credit

from this link: http://www.taxtips.ca/glossary.htm#Dividend

> For an individual with no income other
>   than taxable Canadian dividends which
>   are eligible for the enhanced dividend
>   tax credit, approximately $66,000 can
>   be earned before any federal taxes are
>   payable

So a person can have no job, just invest in market, earn a ton of money in dividends and pocket all of it without paying tax?
While another person earning that same money through a job has to pay tax?

What is missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, yes. That doesn't mean that it's easy to do. The government provides a dividend tax credit since an individual takes on more risk to invest in dividend-paying corporations rather than trading their human capital for an income. Thus, for the most part, $1 earned from dividends is taxed much less than $1 earned from income or interest. Finally, note that foreign dividends are not eligible for the dividend tax credit, and are not preferentially taxed.

Answer (score 8):

The profits that the corporation had to earn to be able to pay you "eligible" dividends for the dividend tax credit were **already taxed**, and at a somewhat high corporate rate, in the case of large public companies with big profits.

The dividend tax credit, which permits an individual to earn a lot from dividends and not pay any *personal* income tax, essentially *recognizes* that the profit making up the dividend was already highly taxed to begin with via *corporate* income tax.  It aims to eliminate double-taxation.

FWIW, if you own and run a small private business in Canada and pay yourself a dividend, such dividends are considered "non-eligible", i.e. you don't get as much a benefit from the dividend tax credit, since small business corporate income tax rates are much lower.

Comment: But the tax was paid by the corporation, not the individual receiving the dividend. So the person receiving the dividend gets to enjoy the dividend tax free? seems it is a rule that favors the dividedn receiver and unfavors the dividend payer

Comment: @Kaushik Yes, the individual investor benefits at the expense of the corporation that paid the tax on the profits.  Works for me.

Comment: @Kaushik: keep in mind that the dividend receiver **owns** the dividend payer, and has a vote in dividend policy.